# WebClient downloads corrupted file in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, webclient

I have a simple code that downloads a file from specified URL and it works great in windows 7, but when i run it in windows 8.1 downloaded file is corrupted. Where is the problem?

This is the code and URL:

```
WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
wClient.DownloadFile(@"http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0", "dl.xlsx");
```

Comment: Tried this code in LINQPad on Windows 8 and it worked as expected, downloading a copy of the file which could be opened in Google Docs. The file corruption may be caused by something else.

Comment: This file is an Excel file with a table and some records, if you put the URL in any browser or download manager they will download  it without problem, also code runs well in windows 7, but it downloads corrupted file in windows 8.1, i'm just wonder why the code not do the same thing in another Windows, I have tried it in 2 different PCs with Windows 8.1 on them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL does not deliver what you expect. Use Fiddler to find out what happens at the HTTP level. You need to find out what the server needs as input to respond with the correct content.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **usr** for help, i found the problem, server returns the file in GZip format so i have adapted the code:

```
public class WebDownload : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

But still i dont know why my initial code runs without problem in my PC!

Comment: This also works for downloading an attachment from tfs (team foundation server) via the rest api. (Windows 10)

Thanks!