# WebClient download file corrupted

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am trying to use C# WebClient to download a file.

Here is the URL:
http://www.czce.com.cn/cn/DFSStaticFiles/Future/2018/20180821/FutureDataClearParams.txt

If I download it manually, everything looks ok. However if I use the WebClient to download the file, the content is corrupted. I have tried to use many different encoding methods. Below is minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Proxy = new WebProxy("some company proxy");
        string url = "http://www.czce.com.cn/cn/DFSStaticFiles/Future/2018/20180821/FutureDataClearParams.txt";
        client.DownloadFile(url, @"D:\file.txt");
    }
}
```

The issue is resolved now, acknowledgements for everyone's help (@Gauravsa , @John). The file is indeed GZipped.

The solution is:

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how it's corrupted?

Comment: Please post some code, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: How did you determine that the file's encoding is UTF-8?

Comment: `WebClient.Encoding` is used during upload, not download. When downloading the encoding set by the server is used instead, so this is a red herring.

Comment: @Lasse That and `DownloadFile` works without issues. I get the exact same file as if I download through my web browser (hence my downvote for the question).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebClient downloads corrupted file in windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206141/webclient-downloads-corrupted-file-in-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.czce.com.cn/cn/DFSStaticFiles/Future/2018/20180821/FutureDataClearParams.txt", 
                        @"c:\Users\Jon\Test\foo.txt");
}
```

or

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
        client.DownloadFile("http://www.czce.com.cn/cn/DFSStaticFiles/Future/2018/20180821/FutureDataClearParams.txt", 
                            "c:\\Users\\Jon\\Test\\foo.txt");
}
```

You can do other File I/O operations like

```
if(!Directory.Exists("c:\\Users\\Jon\\Test\\")
    Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\Users\\Jon\\Test\\");
```

...

Comment: I have tried that, if you open foo.txt, everything is corrupted. compare to the manually downloaded result

Comment: Use Fiddler to find out what happens at the HTTP level. You need to find out what the server needs as input to respond with the correct content.

Comment: @David Could you possible improve your question so that people can give you helpful answers? `DownloadFile` works fine for me and is byte-for-byte identical to the file as downloaded through Google Chrome.

Comment: @David: server might return the file in GZip format

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206141/webclient-downloads-corrupted-file-in-windows-8-1

Comment: @David Following the edit, I think that Gauravsa is on to something. Your company proxy may be employing gzip compression to make the file smaller. Try the modified webclient solution that is linked ^

Comment: @John I have updated the question with an example code that cause the issue on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I test it and work.

For example, look at this console application. It download your file from URL, and saves it to desktop as file.txt. :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                string address = "http://www.czce.com.cn/cn/DFSStaticFiles/Future/2018/20180821/FutureDataClearParams.txt";
                // Save the file to desktop for debugging
                var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                string fileName = desktop + "\\file.txt";
                client.DownloadFile(address, fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted as a comment? As in "Well, it works fine for me. Can you post an [mcve] demonstrating the problem?"

Comment: @John, I have updated the code with a minimal complete and verifiable example except for the proxy part, I have also attached the corrupted result if it helps